# What does the phrase "when to feather the throttle and when to pin in" mean in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, terminology

Here is a sentence from a racer game:

> "You will need a sixth sense for knowing when to **feather the throttle and when to pin in**."

Is it just about increasing or decreasing the speed of a car?

Answer (score 1):

"to feather the throttle" = to press the throttle just a little, as if touched with a feather

Further insight from @FumbleFingers:

> I'm inclined to suppose that feathering the throttle control implies rapidly (but lightly) "tickling" it  (as with feathering the clutch ...)

---

"to pin in" = to press the throttle with maximum force. See the definition for [to pin](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pin):

> **pin** (verb) = to force someone or something to stay in a particular place by putting weight on him, her, or it:
>
> - She was **pinned** (down) under a pile of rubble.
> - A guy leaped out at me and **pinned** me (up) against the wall.

Of course, the (indirect) effect of using the throttle is varying the speed of the car.

Comment: I don't play "racer games", and I don't know exactly how standard game control pads work. But based purely on my knowledge of how *English* works, I'm inclined to suppose that *feathering* the throttle control implies rapidly (but lightly) "tickling" it (as with [feathering the clutch](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22feathering+the+clutch%22), which I ***am*** familiar with). And noting the specific preposition ***in***, I'd guess the throttle control can be "locked" in some way, so a player can maintain (maximum) acceleration without needing to hold the button down continuously.

Comment: I played racer games only using a keyboard, and a long time ago, and I usually lost. But I drive a car, and I provided the best answer I could based on that experience. And I drive a car for "basic" transportation, not for races. I am not familiar with "feathering the clutch".

Comment: If you follow the Google Books link in my earlier comment, and change it to *Sorted by **Date***, you should end up with exactly three citations. Each of which specifically *defines* what the expression means, at the same time as ***using*** it with that sense. After seeing an expression both used ***and defined*** in three different printed contexts, you should be able to say *Ah! **Now** I'm familiar with it!*

Comment: Those quotes did not help me much (I am probably not too bright on these matters), but I found "normal" articles using Google. I think I understand it now. And I also understand that what is good on a bike might not be good at all for a car :D (because of the technological differences). Thanks anyway for the heads-up. I never rode a motorbike.

Comment: I never mentioned any difference between racing motorbikes and cars (*feathering the clutch* means exactly the same for both). The context of those three written examples above include one for a *car*, one for a *motorbike,* and one for a ***bus***. I assume OP's "racer game" isn't for bus drivers, but I've no idea whether it's about cars or bikes.

Comment: I mentioned the difference because of an explanation, stating that clutches for bikes are wet (oiled), while clutches for cars are dry. So although feathering is the same, the effects on the cutch itself are different (apparently; destructive - dry, non-destructive - wet). I have no idea about buses. OP's last word (in the question) was "car", so I assume also that we can exclude buses :)

Comment: For the second expression, you say *force ... to **stay** in a particular place*, which to my mind (particularly with *pin **in***) suggests that the relevant control can be "locked". That's to say, a control button that you can press in hard to lock it ~(on "full throttle", after which you can take your finger off and it will stay like that unless and until you press it hard again to ***release*** the locking / pinning mechanism within the switch.